# Скорость работы цикла (при подключении компонентов)

Tags: delphi

Не могу разобраться почему вот так цикл в функции работает очень быстро:

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
var
  i, c: integer;
begin
  c := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  begin
    if s[i] = '/' then
      Inc(c);
    if c = 3 then
    begin
      Delete(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

А вот так (Вставляю edit и SpinEdit в цикл) то скорость падает в десятки раз:

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
var
  i, c: integer;
begin
  c := 0;
 for i := Length(s) downto 1 do
begin
    if s[i] = frm_Main.Edit1.Text then
      Inc(c);
    if c = frm_Main.SpinEdit1.Value then
    begin
      Delete(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Пробую вынести Edit и SpinEdit за пределы цикла, но ошибка:

```
procedure Del(var s: string);
var
  i, c: integer;
  m,k:string;
begin
  c := 0;
  m := frm_Main.Edit1.text;
  k := frm_Main.SpinEdit1.Value; // но вот тут походу неправильно подключаю
 for i := Length(s) downto 1 do
begin
    if s[i] = m then
      Inc(c);
    if c = k then
    begin
      Delete(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i);
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `k: integer;`, a нe `k: string;`

Answer (score 4):

> А вот так (Вставляю edit и SpinEdit в цикл) то скорость падает в десятки раз:

Дело в том, что `TEdit.Text` - это не поле, а свойство (Property), чтение и запись которого идет через вызов довольно тяжелых функций WinAPI. Посмортите реализацию методов GetText и SetText у TEdit и сами во всем убедитесь.

> Пробую вынести Edit и SpinEdit за пределы цикла, но ошибка:

Во-первых, прочитайте текст ошибки, прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Во-вторых, если задаете вопрос, приводите тест сообщения об ошибке.

В данном случае Igor правильно подсказал - несоответствие типа переменной k и значения, которое вы в него пытаетесь записать.